# Serializable Fields in Magento Collections

Tags: magento-1.7, resource-model

In my resource model I have defined a field as serializable (see property `$_serializableFields` in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`): Magento handles automatically serialization/unserialization of the contents when loading data from the database and before saving the object.

This works perfectly, but when I iterate over a collection of those objects, the field contents are not unserialized automatically. I tried with `$collection->walk('afterLoad')` but soon realized that `unserializeFields()` is triggered in the resource model `load()`, and not in `afterLoad()` like I first thought. What is the best practice in this case? How do I get this field unserialized automatically? I can of course reload the object in my loop, doing something like `$object = $object->load($object->getId())`, but I was wondering if there is a smarter way to achieve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I can of course reload the object in my loop, doing something like `$object = $object->load($object->getId())`

**This is *not* a reload - this is a load**. Items (model instances) in collections *are not* loaded. They merely have had an associative array of result row data applied to them. It's an important and slightly confusing difference between these collection-owned model instances and those which are self-load data through their resource model.

In your collection's `_afterLoad()`, iterate over the `_items` and `unserialize()` the appropriate field:

```
protected function _afterLoad()
{
    parent::_afterLoad();
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $item->setData('field',unserialize($item->getData('field')));
        $item->setDataChanges(false);
        //The above sets items as not dirty.
        //Value will be serialized on save via resource model.
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I know they are not loaded, wrong wording, but thanks for pointing that out! Neat solution indeed, thought there might be an easier way, but this looks just right.

Comment: It would be nice if `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` defined a getter for `_serializableFields` that the collection abstract would use to perform the same logic. That said, it would be easy enough for you to create one in your resource model.

Comment: Also a good idea, to keep the logic inside the resource model. Like that, the collection doesn't need to know which fields need to be unserialized. Even if I only have one field and I'm not planning to add more, it is definitely more consistent.

Answer (score 4):

Or more simply, in your resource model collection:-

```
class Collection 
extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        parent::_afterLoad();
        foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
            $this->getResource()->unserializeFields($item);
            $item->setDataChanges(false);
        }
        return $this;
   }
}
```

Comment: Not working in M2 (2.2.6)

Comment: Nice idea. Works great in Magento 2.3. I prefer this solution over the accepted answer, because it uses Magento unserialization utility instead of PHP's unserialize. This way it respects Magento's serialization mode.

Comment: Agree about preferring to pass off the work of unserialization to the `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb::unserializeFields($object)` method. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do this for product collections I added an event listener to `catalog_product_collection_load_after` and to iterate over all products.

```
/**
 * Apply backend manipulations of attributes to collection items.
 * Listens to catalog_product_collection_load_after.
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer
 */
public function loadCollectionAttributes(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        /* @var $product Limora_Catalog_Model_Product */
        foreach ($product->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute */
            $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb::$_serializableFields` with `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb::beforeAddLoadedItem`

Add this code to yor custom collection

```
// Model/ResourceModel/SomeModel/Collection.php    

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
protected function beforeAddLoadedItem(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $item)
{
    $this->getResource()->unserializeFields($item);
    return parent::beforeAddLoadedItem($item);
}
```

For **grid collection**:

You should add method to resource model:

```
// Model/ResourceModel/SomeModel.php

public function unserializeDataProviderDocumentFields(Document $object)
{
    foreach ($this->_serializableFields as $field => list($serializeDefault, $unserializeDefault)) {
        $this->_unserializeField($object, $field, $unserializeDefault);
    }
}
```

And use this method in grid collection instead unserializeFields:

```
// Model/ResourceModel/SomeModel/Grid/Collection.php

protected function beforeAddLoadedItem(DataObject $item)
{
    $this->getResource()->unserializeDataProviderDocumentFields($item);
    return parent::beforeAddLoadedItem($item);
}
```