# Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract's afterLoad() doesn't get called in certain cases?

Tags: custom-attributes

I have created a custom attribute defined by a module. I am doing this to define a custom Input Renderer in the admin. This attribute serializes/unserializes its content within an afterLoad() override, like this:

```
<?php
    class WarrantyLengths_Attr_Model_Custom extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract{
        public function beforeSave($object)
        {
            //before saving the product check if the attribute is an array.
            //if it is, serialize it for saving in the db
            $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
            $data = $object->getData($attributeCode);
            if (is_array($data)) {
                $data = array_filter($data);
                $object->setData($attributeCode, serialize($data));
            }
            return parent::beforeSave($object);
        }
        public function afterLoad($object) {
            //after loading the product, check if the value for custom_values is not an array. If it's not try to unserialize the value.
            $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
            $data = $object->getData($attributeCode);
            if (!is_array($data)) {
                $object->setData($attributeCode, @unserialize($data));
            }
            return parent::afterLoad($object);
        }
    }
```

This works fine ... *for some templates.* I can do a **$_product->getData('warranty_lengths')** within catalog/product/view.phtml just fine - afterLoad() provides unserialized content from a getData() call.

But... this is *not* the case for catalog/product/list.phtml. The attribute value is returned unserialized.

Why might this be? Smells like a bug to me. I'm developing under Magento ver. 1.9.2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When derived from a collection, the (resource) models' `load()` method is not called. This leads to the attributes not being post-processed by their backend models' `afterLoad()` method. It's not a bug, it's a feature.

The `afterLoad()` method can still be triggered manually, e.g.:

```
$lenAttribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('warranty_lengths');
$lenAttribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($_product);
$warrantyLengths = $_product->getData('warranty_lengths');
```

See also [Serializable Fields in Magento Collections](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/5237) for a more lightweight approach.

Comment: Ahhh - I see. I should have realized that that list.phtml works with collections and view.phtml does not. It makes sense now, thanks!